# Rails missing template after project move

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I've moved the project to another PC, installed Ruby and Rails - all working OK.

After running the server, there is no CSS (no bootstrap) and now it is saying that my edit template is missing `(edit.html.erb)`. This is not the only one, but the weird thing is, that the search page and index work OK.

The only issue that I see is that if I browse to those files, some `*.html.erb` files show that `IE icon` and the `'Type'` is a HTML document, rather than a ERB file. Any file that shows as being an ERB file works, but anything that shows as being a HTML file does not show in the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: which folder you exactly copied ?

Comment: The whole project folder

Comment: you have Vista OS or something ? Did you try to copy the app to another location ? or even to pen drive and test it on your friend's computer..

Answer (score 0):

The new windows machine was detecting some files as, for example, edit.html.erb.html.

Opening them back up in an IDE, resaving them as just edit.html.erb and overwriting the original files fixed it. Very strange.